# Create infinite scrolling gallery View

Tags: android, android-gallery

I have a very simple `Gallery` which I use to scroll through some pictures with a 2 seconds interval. My question: *how to make this gallery "infinite" so the first picture comes again after the last one?*

**NOTE**

- I'm aware of the fact that Gallery is claimed deprecated
- I did not perform any optimizations to my code yet since that is just a quick test on a high-end tablet. Though your suggestions regarding optimization are also appreciated

Main:

```
      public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private Gallery ga;
private Runnable r = null;
private Handler mHandler = null;
private MediaPlayer mp;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setUpGallery();

            mHandler = new Handler();
    r = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            mHandler.postDelayed(r, 2000);
            ga.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT, null);

        }

    };

    r.run();
           }

            private void setUpGallery() {
    ga = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.gallery);
    ga.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.you);
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.reset();
            mp.release();

        }
    });

}
```

Adapter:

```
                 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private int[] pics = { R.drawable.s1, R.drawable.s2, R.drawable.s3,
        R.drawable.s4, R.drawable.s5, R.drawable.s6, R.drawable.s7,
        R.drawable.s8, R.drawable.s9, R.drawable.s10, R.drawable.s11,
        R.drawable.s12, R.drawable.s13, R.drawable.s14 };
private Context ctx;


public ImageAdapter(Context c) {

    ctx = c;

}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return pics.length;

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {

    return arg0;

}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {

    return arg0;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
    holder.img = new ImageView(ctx);
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), pics[position]);
    holder.img.setImageBitmap(ImageHelper.getRoundedCornerBitmap(bmp, 10));

    return holder.img;

}

static class ViewHolder {

    public ViewHolder() {

    }

    ImageView img;

}

    }
```

Comment: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless. Could use this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make custom Gallaryadapter by extending class..

I just found solution from here

http://blog.blundell-apps.com/infinite-scrolling-gallery/

i may be helpfull for you;

Also you can try this in your code..

```
mHandler = new Handler();
    r = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            if (count == adapter.getCount()) {
                count = 0;

                ga.setSelection(0);
                mHandler.postDelayed(r, 2000);
            } else {
                mHandler.postDelayed(r, 2000);
                ga.onKeyDown(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT, null);
                count++;

            }
        }

    };


    r.run();
```

Answer (score 0):

well, actually the solution is much easier than I thought. It might not be suitable for everyone but it's OK in my case. Just added a Random to the `getView()` method

```
  Random rnd  = new Random();

    if(position>=pics.length){
        position = rnd.nextInt(13);
    }
```